# draw rubberband from 2d point to 3d point

Tags: three.js

Iam trying to draw a rubberband from mouse coordinates converted to 3d points,[rubberband link](https://jsfiddle.net/goa3w3gw/1/) i have attached working code of it.

1. rubberband got rotated while drawing why?

```
geometry.vertices[0] = new THREE.Vector3(startPoint.x, startPoint.y, startPoint.z);
geometry.vertices[1] = new THREE.Vector3(endPoint.x, startPoint.y, startPoint.z);
geometry.vertices[2] = new THREE.Vector3(endPoint.x, endPoint.y, startPoint.z);
geometry.vertices[3] = new THREE.Vector3(startPoint.x, endPoint.y, startPoint.z);
geometry.vertices[4] = new THREE.Vector3(startPoint.x, startPoint.y, startPoint.z);
```

could anyone give their suggestion, what went wrong in my code?.

Comment: It's unclear, to me anyhow, what you're asking. Can you edit to give a more detailed description of the problem you're encountering?

Comment: @Radio check the [link](https://jsfiddle.net/goa3w3gw/1/), select click me button to enable rubberband drawing, then on mouse down draw rubberband, it draw correctly, but when model rotated, and i draw  a rubberband, it got rotated.